# Integrating SpamAssassin into Postfix

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I have set up a postfix+spamassassin mail filter to protect my Exchange 2010 server.
The matter is I'd like to use a custom tag string instead of the default `*****SPAM*****`.
I have already changed the `rewrite_header` in `local.cf` but spams are still tagged with the default `*****SPAM*****`.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" etc. to the title. Marking an answer as accepted is enough: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was use the conf file of amavis (somewhere in /etc/ ) that do the tagging.

Hope this may help!

Comment: Could you specify where exactly this conf file is or should be put?

Comment: It is located in:        /etc/amavis/conf.d/20-debian_defaults  and look for the line line where it is mentionned:     $sa_spam_subject_tag =